# Should we keep the [troubleshooting] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tag

We have this tag [troubleshooting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) (253 questions) that is of questionable utility. Should we keep it?

- It is definitely a **dependent** tag. If you saw a post that had just this one tag, you would not have any indication from tags alone about what kind of problem it is.
- It might be a **meta** tag that describes the asker more than the question itself. Troubleshooting is a valuable technique, but sometimes a problem can be diagnosed without troubleshooting if the observer has sufficient knowledge.
- It may be **overly broad**. I can easily find hundreds of troubleshoting questions that don't have this tag yet. For example, almost every [boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot) question is about troubleshooting. Surely we wouldn't want to add it?

Comment: Interesting....the [tag:troubleshooting] tag suddenly has zero questions.

Comment: @Allan I'm as surprised as anyone.

Comment: Did someone do a merge or something?

Answer (score 2):

No, [troubleshooting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) is a meta tag. It describes a thinking and not the actual question. Without a very good definition of how a question could be about troubleshooting solely, it would either apply to all questions or not be helpful in my experience.

If you are troubleshooting an OS - tag it with the os. Hardware, use the hardware tag. Services, use the appropriate tag.

If someone asks about the theory of troubleshooting, that should probably be on another site since this place is all about Apple hardware, software and services.

Answer (score 1):

[troubleshooting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) is a valid tag and should be maintained.

Addressing the OP's concerns in order:

> It is definitely a dependent tag. If you saw a post that had just this one tag, you would not have any indication from tags alone about what kind of problem it is.

This is quite common with a countless number of tags.  Many times folks will ask a software or OS related question with a single take like [macbook-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro).  What we do in cases like this is

1. Ask for clarification
2. Edit the tags for relevancy

> It might be a **meta** tag that describes the asker more than the question itself.

Every tag in some way describes the asker in some way - what they want, what they need, and/or what they have.

> Troubleshooting is a valuable technique, but sometimes a problem can be diagnosed without troubleshooting if the observer has sufficient knowledge.

Observation ***is*** a troubleshooting technique.  However, this isn't a one sided relationship on this site.  It's designed to *teach* folks how to do things, not just blindly answer questions.  I myself have answered questions asking *how* to troubleshoot problems:  [How to determine the cause of MacBook battery not charging?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328979/how-to-determine-the-cause-of-macbook-battery-not-charging/328981#328981)

> It may be **overly broad**. I can easily find hundreds of troubleshooting questions that don't have this tag yet. For example, almost every [boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot) question is about troubleshooting.

Any tag by itself has the potential to be overly broad (i.e. [mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac))  This doesn't mean we should just up and remove it.  What we should do is what I referenced in the first answer:

1. Ask for clarification
2. Edit tags for relevancy

Comment: Thank you for providing a rebuttal. Although I personally remain unconvinced that this is a valuable tag, I am very happy to have a counter argument presented.

Comment: @Nic - *you* may not find it valuable but there's likely others who do.  Having multiple vectors to get to the same destination can only help, not hurt.

Answer (score -1):

No, let's not keep the [troubleshooting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) tag. We don't want meta tags and dependent tags to be part of our tag library.

Comment: What is your proposal in regards of existing questions with this tag (especially does which only have this tag)?

Comment: @nohillside I could not locate any questions that had *only* [tag:troubleshooting]. There are around 10 questions with only two tags, and most of them have very obvious tags that could be added. But generally speaking, my proposal here is to delete the troubleshooting tag and not bring in anything to replace it.

Comment: And pro tip: there's a SEDE query for [finding questions that have just a singleton tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148977/search-for-singleton-tags-on-questions).